# Infinite loop when trying to delete Table Style programmatically but when manually resumed the loop it works

Tags: excel, vba

the title basically summarizes my problem.
I am struggling with finding the culprit here.

The subroutine goes into infinite loop when launched automatically but when trying to debug and go step by step, it works as intended.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub insert_custom_table(ByVal table_range As Range)
    Dim target_worksheet As Worksheet
    Set target_worksheet = table_range.Parent
    
    Dim table_style As TableStyle
    
    Do While table_style Is Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        
        With target_worksheet.Parent
            Set table_style = .TableStyles("tablestyle_df")
            
            If table_style Is Nothing Then
                Set table_style = .TableStyles.Add("tablestyle_df")
            Else
                table_style.Delete
                Set table_style = Nothing
            End If
        End With

        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop

' rest of code

End Sub
```

Comment: Try avoid to use While Loops, using for each loop and for loop when you processing large dataset. I used to facing infinite loop problem when working sub alone is fine, but combine with other sub procedure then infinite loop. For loop work the best in most case

Comment: I don't understand your logik. Why do you loop at all? If I understand you correctly, you want to delete and (re-)create the table-style with name `"tablestyle_df"`?

Comment: @FunThomas, yeah, I want to be extra sure no manual changes were made to the table style so I recreate it each time.

Comment: @hollson: Yeah, understand that, but why a loop?

Comment: @FunThomas: I included a loop there because for some reason I was receiving an error when trying to delete an existing table style (visible when iterating through all) but when manually resuming the code after the error, the table style that was having an issue with deleting actually got deleted. I was trying to make sure the object gets assigned eventually, thought maybe the code was executing too fast or something but it went into infinite loop for some reason instead even though if I break the infinite loop and resume the code, it gets executed just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid While loops with no definite end. Due to unknown reasons `table_style` may never not be nothing, which would cause infinite looping.

Instead, rephrase your loop to have a definite start and end:

```vb
Sub insert_custom_table(ByVal table_range As Range)
    Dim target_worksheet As Worksheet
    Set target_worksheet = table_range.Parent
    
    Dim table_style As TableStyle
    
    For Each table_style In target_worksheet.Parent.TableStyles
        If table_style.Name <> "tablestyle_df" Then table_style.Delete
    Next table_style

' rest of code

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work! I was so stubborn to force the object to assign eventually in a loop but did not think to just iterate through all table styles and delete the one where the name matches instead. Thanks, sometimes simpler solutions are the best :)

Comment: This will delete *all* table styles except `"tablestyle_df"` - is that what you want?

Comment: I just replaced the is not equal to sign with is equal to as I wanted to re-create the table style all over.

Comment: The solution worked for a couple of runs and now I receive an -2147417848 Method 'Delete' of object 'TableStyle' failed error again, what the hell is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Your while-loop makes no sense, there is nothing you need to loop about. If you simply want to delete an existing TableStyle, just do so.

`TableStyles` is a collection, and in a collection you can access an element either via index number of via name (very similar to the `Worksheets`-collection of a workbook). If you know the name, you can just write

```
.TableStyles("tablestyle_df").delete
```

Now the only small issue is that this will raise a runtime error (*error 9 - Subscript out of range*) if the style doesn't exist. Simply ignore that error by enclose the statement (but only that single statement!!!) with an `On Error Resume Next`-clause. If the style does not exist, you don't need to delete is. So all you need is

```
With target_worksheet.Parent
    On Error Resume Next      ' Ignore the error if delete fails because style does not exist
    .TableStyles("tablestyle_df").delete
    On Error Goto 0
    Set table_style = .TableStyles.Add("tablestyle_df")
End With
```

Comment: Just copy pasting from previous comment, I included a loop there because for some reason I was receiving an error when trying to delete an existing table style (visible when iterating through all) but when manually resuming the code after the error, the table style that was having an issue with deleting actually got deleted. I was trying to make sure the object gets assigned eventually, thought maybe the code was executing too fast or something but it went into infinite loop for some reason instead even though if I break the infinite loop and resume the code, it gets executed just fine.

Comment: As your code is eating up all errors, it's not clear what exactly is going on. You will get into an endless loop when the delete fails. Still don't see any reason for looping.

Comment: When I remove the error ignore and run the code again on my original piece of code, the existing table style object gets assigned properly and is not nothing. When the code enters the .delete phase, I receive an -2147417848 Method 'Delete' of object 'TableStyle' failed error for some reason. When I resume the code and it enters another loop iteration the error doesn't show. But when it runs on full auto it enters infinite loop. This is what I am struggling with understanding but iterating through all table styles and deleting the one with matching name seems to work.